# Risk about world writable file

Tags: linux, permissions

I  know having world writable file can be dangerous and many people recommend to not have world writable file on your system.

In order to "protect" my Linux, I searched for every world writable file using `find / -perm -0002 -type f`. Thanks to this command, I found a world writable file under my root_directory `/root/a_directory/world_writable_file`. As my `/root` directory is 700, other user cant edit the world writable file.

So my question is, what is the risk if I have world writable file under a directory which can't be access by other users (lack of x right for other) ?

For example, am I safe if `/root/directory1/world_writable_file.sh` is 777 and `/directory1/` is 700. Is there no risk in this situation ?

Comment: It seems you already know the answer. So you have any other specific purpose asking this question?

Comment: It want to be really sure about this issue. Maybe there was some tricks i dont know.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of permissions seems to be correct, but may not be complete.

In order to access a file, the user making the request needs access to all the path elements to that file.  For directories this means needing `x` permissions to be able to traverse that directory.

So a file with permission `777` in a directory with permission `700` would appear to be unreachable by anyone who isn't the directory owner.

For example:

```
$ sudo ls -al XX
total 40
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Dec 21 07:43 .
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 36864 Dec 21 07:43 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root     0 Dec 21 07:43 yy
```

I can not read or write the `yy` file because I can not traverse the `XX` directory.

```
$ cat XX/yy
cat: XX/yy: Permission denied
$ echo test >> XX/yy
/bin/ksh: XX/yy: cannot create [Permission denied]
```

However, traditional permissions are not the only way of granting access to files; there are *also* ACLs...

```
$ sudo setfacl -m u:sweh:rwx XX
$ ls -ld XX        
drwxrwx---+ 2 root root 4096 Dec 21 07:43 XX/
$ echo test >> XX/yy
$ cat XX/yy         
test
```

So now, even though the directory permission appears to be `770`, I can still read-write to the file, because the ACL grants it.  The `+` at the end of the permissions list shows there's an ACL

```
drwxrwx---+ 2 root root 4096 Dec 21 07:43 XX/
```

In your specific case, there's an overlap between how ACLs and traditional permissions overlap.  Notice the `setfacl` command set the mode to `770`.  If we set this back to your `700`...

```
$ sudo chmod 700 XX
$ ls -ld XX
drwx------+ 2 root root 4096 Dec 21 07:43 XX/
```

Now the ACL is still present, but has effectively *not* granted access:

```
$ getfacl XX
# file: XX
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:sweh:rwx                   #effective:---
group::---
mask::---
other::---
```

Notice the `#effective:---` entry.  That's because the `mask` value was modified by  `chmod` when setting the group value; it's a subtle interaction between ACLs and file permissions.

And so..

```
$ cat XX/yy        
cat: XX/yy: Permission denied
```

To cut a long story story... your world writeable file inside a `700` directory should be safe, but a similar file in a `770` directory may not be.